# Passing value to a function through R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, cmd, rscript

I have a function created in R for test purpose that will get two values, add them and assign the result to a variable and the result will be stored  in a csv file. Below is my r code

```
  f2 <- function(x, y) {
  args=(commandArgs(TRUE))
  z1 <- x + y
  z2 <- x + 2*y
  b <- list(z1, z2) 
  write.csv(b,"testfun.csv",row.names=F)
  print(z1)
  print(z2)
  print(b)
}
```

The code is working fine and i am able to pass the values to my function through r console. However I want to do this using R CMD and not in a r console. This is because i have a web application that will invoke this function on click of a button.

I tried to invoke the function using the below code

```
Rscript test.R 5 100
```

and

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args x=3 y=5' test.R test.out &
```

However the function is not getting invoked and i am not getting the output. When i run the above R CMD BATCH statement i'm getting an error like ''--args'' no such file or directory.

> Fatal error: cannot open file ''--args': No such file or directory

So i moved the  '--args x=3 y=5' values after the test.R something like

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore test.R '--args x=3 y=5' test.out &
```

On executing the above i'm getting my r sript saved in the directory and not the my expected output. I tried all the ways from the below link

[Passing command line arguments to R CMD BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167178/passing-command-line-arguments-to-r-cmd-batch)

Can anyone shed some light over this? I need to invoke my function along with some parameter through rscript or r cmd.

Comment: You have different script names in your attempts. Please fix it.

Comment: Apologize.. Fixed the script name

Comment: Any help for my post.... :(

Comment: Late response: I think if your `test.R` file does only contain the R code from your question it does nothing but creating a function - **but never calls it**! Add a call to function at the end and process the args correctly. `args` is a list of character vectors that must be executed with `eval(parse(args[[i]]))` if you want to execute the code in the arguments...

Comment: For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167178/passing-command-line-arguments-to-r-cmd-batch

Comment: I can't get to --args to work either