# How to pass in function parameters for an R file when run from terminal?

Tags: r, function, terminal, rscript

I have a file on my computer that I want to run from the command line.  This file would have some stuff happening within it + a function.

For example I have a global variable, start_value=10 and then I call a function further down in the Rscript.  I want to run this script while passing in parameters

I tried to find out online how to do this, but I have had no luck.
I receive this error:

```
  Error in help_function(x, y) : object 'x' not found
```

When running like this:

```
    Rscript helpme.R 100 10
```

-

```
  ##?? saw this someplaces when searching, but couldn't get it to work
 args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

 starting_value=10

 help_function = function(x,y){


     division =x/y
     answer=starting_value + division
 return(answer)
}

 help_function(x,y)
```

Comment: You need to pick the arguments out of `args`, and process them if necessary, [as for example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167178/passing-command-line-arguments-to-r-cmd-batch/14167417#14167417).

Comment: rather obvious that R can't find `x` if you never define it in your script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`commandArgs`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/commandArgs.html) function returns a character vector with the arguments passed to the command line (`trailingOnly = TRUE` removes the `"RScript helpme.R"` part).

In your case :

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# parse your command line arguments
x <- as.numeric(args[1]) # args[1] contains "100"
y <- as.numeric(args[2]) # args[2] contains "10"

# ...continue with your script here
```