# Execute batch file from Matlab

Tags: r, windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd

I have a Matlab function that finds the path where this function is within my pc and then runs a bat file on that same directory. This bat file is meant to execute an R script but for a strange reason is failing to do so.

This is my Matlab function:

```matlab
function [] = myFunction(arg)

  % Find the directory of the executing script
  thisDir = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));

  % Save arg as a csv on this directory, this will be read by my R script
  tmpDir = strcat(thisDir,'/tmp.csv');
  csvwrite(tmpDir,arg);

  % Specify the command to run
  dosCommand = ['call "' thisDir '/runRscript.bat"'];
  dos(dosCommand);

end
```

The bat file has the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH runRScipt.R
```

When I run the function in Matlab I get the below message:

> C:\Users\...mypath...>"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH
>   runRscript.R

Since I get this message in Matlab I have no doubt it is finding and reading the batch file, but it fails to execute the R script. I know the bat file works as expected since I can run it through the command line (with the command that should be the "dosCommand" on the Matlab script) or by clicking twice on the .bat file.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167178/passing-command-line-arguments-to-r-cmd-batch) might be related. 
Also there seems to be a specific package for it, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31708-running-r-within-matlab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. For a strange reason the dos() command would not work, but the  system() command will do the job. Then the code will look like this:

```
function [] = myFunction(arg)

  % Find the directory of the executing script
  thisDir = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));

  % Save arg as a csv on this directory, this will be read by my R script
  tmpDir = strcat(thisDir,'/tmp.csv');
  csvwrite(tmpDir,arg);

  % Specify the command to run
  sysCommand = ['call "' thisDir '/runRscript.bat"'];
  system(sysCommand);

end
```

And the batch file:

> "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH runRScipt.R

Answer (score 0):

Instead of R.exe please try Rscript.exe. R.exe runs R code in interactive mdoe while Rscript runs the code in batch mode. Ideally you should find Rscript executable in the same path as in R executable (i.e. "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64" in your case)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @abhiieor. Rscript.exe is on the same path, but even if I change it, I still can't execute it from Matlab. Furthermore, with this change the batch file no longer executes the R script by double clicking it.